# HTTP method’s error: 401 (Unauthorized) on React & Django(DRF)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-401

I completed manipulating authentication with token by referring [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/django-rest-framework-with-react-jwt-authentication-part-1-a24b24fa83cd), and then I’m trying to create a crud function such creating post, displaying posts, etc… . However, I have an error when I fetched the url which displays posts(IE, fetching url I defined as “index” method on views.py of app for auth manipulation), I have 401 error even though I can access by using url of the backend without any error even on terminal.

I found some config codes which are related to authentication and permission for manipulation of authentication with token on settings.py causes this error, since when I delete these codes, the crud function works.  But obviously authentication function no longer works (index method on views.py retrieve only token, another informations are filled blank) by this solution.

```
//fetch method on frontend
try{
              const res = await fetch(`${base_url}/accounts/current_user/`,{
                method:'GET',
                headers:{
                  Authorization:`JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
              })
              const data = await res.json();
        
              setUsername(data.username);

              console.log(data)
              
            }catch(err){console.log(err)};

//fetch posts on frontend
const getProblems = async() =>{
            const res = await fetch(base_url+'/problems/index');

            const data = await res.json();

            setProblems(data);
        }

//views.py on app for auth manipulation
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_current_user(request):
    serializer = GetFullUserSerializer(request.user)
    print(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data)

//settings.py(related to auth, cors):

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
)

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'new_sns.utils.custom_jwt_response_handler',   
}
```

I have another files such serializer.py, urls.py,but they are absolutely same as the article I extracted.

I guess I misunderstand something around configuration. I would like to hear some of suggestions. Please let me know if you think if there may be problems on another files which I didn't attach on here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` to `` Authorization:`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')} ``.

In case this won't work, try [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/) - package recommended on DRF's docs.

> JSON Web Token is a fairly new standard which can be used for
> token-based authentication. Unlike the built-in TokenAuthentication
> scheme, JWT Authentication doesn't need to use a database to validate
> a token. A package for JWT authentication is
> djangorestframework-simplejwt which provides some features as well as
> a pluggable token blacklist app.

[django-api-logger](https://pypi.org/project/drf-api-logger/) and [axios-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-jwt) may also come handy.